# How to get rid of warning IL2080?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj, roslyn-code-analysis

In the bellow code for line

```
ConstructorInfo constructorInfoObj = ValueType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
```

I get this warning:

> ValueDescriptor.cs(58, 50): [IL2080] 'this' argument does not
> satisfy
> 'DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicParameterlessConstructor' in
> call to 'System.Type.GetConstructor(Type[])'. The field
> 'MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.Internals.ValueDescriptor.ValueType'
> does not have matching annotations. The source value must declare at
> least the same requirements as those declared on the target location
> it is assigned to.

This only occurs if I add

```
<IsTrimmable>true</IsTrimmable>
<EnableTrimAnalyzer>true</EnableTrimAnalyzer>
```

to the .csproj-file.

Why is this warning thrown, and what has it to do with trimmable ? 
How to remedy this without removing `IsTrimmable` and without setting `EnableTrimAnalyzer` to false ?

This is the code for context:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.Internals
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class of all value descriptor classes.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class ValueDescriptor
    {
        public Type ValueType;

        internal ValueDescriptor(Type valueType)
        {
            this.ValueType = valueType;
        }

        public object CreateValue()
        {
            ConstructorInfo constructorInfoObj = ValueType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            
            return constructorInfoObj.Invoke(null);
        }
        
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Full source of this class:
https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/master/MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel/MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Internals/ValueDescriptor.cs#L58

Comment: What is `ValueType.GetConstructor`? Can you please provide a full [mre]?

Comment: _"Why is this warning thrown, and what has it to do with trimmable ?"_ - you have enabled trimming which will trim parts which are considered unused by the compiler,  which obviously can affect the reflection code, hence the warning (note that compiler can give quite some false positives here). Some details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75672166/2501279).

Comment: Guru Stron: Sorry, missed that. ValueType is just a field of type System.Type in class ValueDescriptor.

Comment: And no attributes attached to that property?

Comment: @Ralf: Yep, no attributes. For reference: https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/master/MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel/MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Internals/ValueDescriptor.cs#L58

Comment: I was doing something similar and in my case that one was a false positive, so I just ignored it (have tested against published version).

Comment: You may try adding     `[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicParameterlessConstructor)]`. Asp.Net does it for its startup type also. See https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingStartupAttribute.cs,34

Comment: @Ralf: No you cannot, DynamicallyAccessedMembers is internal, not public.

Comment: @StefanSteiger you can try other options from corresponding enum, like `NonPublicConstructors | PublicConstructors`

Comment: The warning is real enough, the diagnostic is however not accurate.  You need to watch out, this code can easily fail after trimming.  When the type that the ValueType member refers to got eliminated.  The code analyzer otherwise can't figure out exactly what type might cause the problem, all it sees is Type, and fumbles to assuming it might be ValueDescriptor.  This code just isn't all that safe to trim, if you are going to use it then you'll need to test thoroughly.  Consider filing a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

So fix can look like:

```cs
internal ValueDescriptor(string valueName, 
    [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.NonPublicConstructors)] Type valueType, 
    Type memberType,
    MemberInfo memberInfo,
    VDFlags flags)
{
    this.ValueType = valueType;
    // ...
}

/// <summary>
/// Type of the described value, e.g. typeof(Int32) for an NInt.
/// </summary>
[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.NonPublicConstructors)]
public Type ValueType;
```

But then you will need to propagate the attribute to all places where it will be used (also the attribute and the enum should be public).

Comment: This just causes a lot more warnings, and what's worse, they can't be fixed.

Comment: @StefanSteiger I gave only a quick pick so can't verify or deny that. Closer look will take some time, maybe in the evening I'll give it a try.