# JsonSerializer.Deserialize not finding setters in deserializing class on Linux

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

When running the below example, I get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: JsonPropertyInfo 'test' defined in type 'Test.Config' is marked required but does not specify a setter.

If I don't include the `JsonRequired` attribute on the parameter, then it does not produce the error but then I get a default instantiation of my config object instead of one deserialized from my file

This happens only when running on Linux. On Windows it deserializes fine.

```
public class Config
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public int test { get;  set; } = 1;
}


JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath)){
    config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Config>(reader.BaseStream, options);
}
```

JSON file:

```json
{
  "test": 2
}
```

Comment: Double check the filepath for upper vs lower case letters. Linux filenames are case sensitive and is often the cause of linux only isues.

Comment: @Ben then prolly there would be FileNotFoundException ....

Comment: Where does 'NumberOfSensorInfoFetchThreads' come from? If you have sample code then show the error that is thrown by that sample code or show the real code.

Comment: How do you deploy the app? Is it trimmed?

Comment: Does `[DynamicDependency(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.All, typeof(Config))]` help at all?

Comment: @GuruStron Guru, that was it. I was debugging on windows and deploying to linux. The deploy was trimming unused assemblies. After turning that off it is working. If you create an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are trying to run a trimmed application version.

Read more:

- [Trimming options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-7-0)
- [DynamicDependencyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.dynamicdependencyattribute?view=net-7.0#remarks)
- Also consider using [`System.Text.Json` source generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-source-generator/)
- [Similar issue with `Newtonsoft.Json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75673682/2501279)